# Importing dates (US vs, Europe) into Access

Tags: vba, date, ms-access, import

I have a  tool (macro) that creates a txt file for the user and sends it to a shared network drive.  My overnight process imports those txt files into an Office 365 Access database.

One of the fields in the txt file is a date field.  Depending on the user's setting (location) the date field looks like either mm/dd/yyyy (US) or dd/mm/yyyy (Europe).

The date field in the Access database is formatted as Date / Time.  The dates in the table get imported into the database the way they appear on the txt file.

When running queries and using the date field as a criteria, I get more records than expected due to the different date formats.

I'm wondering if there is a way to get all of the dates in the same format during the import process or maybe run another query after the import to "standardize" the dates for easier review.

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.  Have a great week..........

Comment: You should write dates in a common format, eg https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html. It's too late when reading the data because the import cannot guess if 05/02/2022 is 2nd of May or 5th of Feb. And if you would get a file from *my* computer, you even have to deal with 02.05.2022

Comment: Yes, always use the format `yyyy-mm-dd` as @FunThomas recommends, and your trouble will go away.

Comment: @FunThomas............Thanks............That is a great suggestion.  I'm going to take another look at the user's tool and try formatting the dates before writing to the txt file.  I think that will resolve the issue I have going forward.

Comment: @Gustav............Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm going to give that a try............

Comment: I ran a test file yesterday and everything imported into the database except the start and end dates.  Both dates were formatted as yyyy-mm-dd.  I think the issue is that the database fields are date / time.  I'm hoping if I change property to short date, it should work.  At least I hope so.  Anyway,.....more testing on this change is needed